# Utilizar recursão em Python

Tags: python, recursão

Estou iniciando em Python. Fiz esta rotina, mas tenho que transformar para utilizar RECURSÃO, que para mim ainda é confuso:

```
def incomodam(n):
    incom = ''
    if n < 0:
        return incom
    elif n == 1:
        incom = 'incomoda '
        return incom
    for i in range(n):
        incom += 'incomodam '
    return incom


def elefante(n):
    elef = ''
    if n < 1:
        return elef
    if n == 1:
        elef = 'Um elefante ' + incomodam(n) + 'muita gente\n'
        return elef
    if n == 2:
        elef = str(n) + ' elefantes ' + incomodam(n) + 'muito mais\n'
        return elef
    else:
        elef = str(n-1) + ' elefantes incomodam muita gente\n'
        elef += str(n) + ' elefantes ' + incomodam(n) + 'muito mais\n'
        return elef

def elefantes(n):
    frase = ''
    i = 1   
    while i <= n:
        frase += (elefante(i))
        i += 1
    print(frase)
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: como implementar a recursão nesta rotina

Comment: Recursão é chamar a função dentro dela mesma. Basta você fazer isso e pronto, já tem sua recursão. Provavelmente não é a resposta que você espera, mas é que sua pergunta não está específica o suficiente.

Comment: Se quer estudar recursão, eu sugiro que escolha problemas que são naturalmente recursivos (árvores, por exemplo). Tentar aplicar a um problema no qual a solução recursiva é pior e mais complicada só vai te confundir e no fim não vai ajudar tanto assim, na minha opinião. Ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15346774). Alguns exemplos em que a solução recursiva foi melhor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/529245/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/412524/112052

Comment: E como disse que está iniciando, segue uma versão simplificada do código não-recursivo: https://ideone.com/l6PDjA (repare que vc complicou à toa)

Answer (score -1):

Com o seguinte código você teria uma função recursiva:

```
def elefantes(n, todos=True):
    if not todos:
        elef = ''
        if n == 1:
            elef = 'Um elefante incomoda muita gente\n'
            return elef
        elif n == 2:
            elef = '2 elefantes incomodam muito mais\n'
            return elef
        else:
            elef = f'{n - 1} elefantes incomodam muita gente\n'
            elef += f'{n} elefantes incomodam muitos mais\n'
            return elef
    if todos and n >= 1:
        frase = ''
        i = 1   
        while i <= n:
            frase += (elefantes(i, todos=False))
            i += 1
        print(frase)
    else:
        print()
```

Apesar disso, não é uma implementação muito interessante. O parâmetro opcional 'todos', que foi usado para conseguir tornar recursiva, basicamente faz um papel de dividir a função em duas completamente diferente uma da outra. Diferente de uma implementação para calcular um fatorial ou um fibonacci, por exemplo, que se utiliza da mesma função em todo o processo.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).